# Is Mapper.Map in AutoMapper thread-safe?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm looking up [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper) code now (evaluating it for one of projects I'm working on), and, frankly speaking, I'm quite surprised:

- The library API is based on a single static access point (`Mapper` type), so generally any of its methods must be thread safe
- But I didn't find ANY evidence of this in code.

All I was able to find is [this issue](http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/3197), but even the statement made there seems incorrect: if `Map` doesn't use thread-safe data structures internally, it can't be considered as thread-safe as well, if I'm going to call `CreateMap` in non-concurrent context, but concurrently with `Map`.

I.e. the only possible usage pattern of AutoMapper in e.g. ASP.NET MVC application is:

```
lock (mapperLock) {
    ... Mapper.AnyMethod(...) ...
}
```

Obviously, if I'm correct, that's a huge lack.

So I have two questions:

- Am I correct?
- If yes, what's the best alternative to AutoMapper that doesn't have this issue?

Comment: The main key seems to be the double-checked lookup via `ThreadSafeList<TypeMap> _typeMaps`; what makes you think it is not thread-safe? What ***specifically*** do you believe is not thread-safe?

Comment: Is TypeMap an immutable object?

Comment: you tell me! (and the questions is also: even if it isn't, is it inappropriately updated at any point, other than by you). You've made a claim that it is not thread-safe; please elaborate on what you think is not safe. Note that typically the strategy (once built) is not updated, so the only thing that needs protecting is access to the strategy-cache, which appears to be done correctly.

Comment: Looking up the code now once more. Actually, I missed usage of `ThreadSafeList` there.

Comment: Am I correct that `TypeMap` entry is added right on `Mapper.CreateMap` call, and further modified by `IMappingExpression` methods? If yes, there is an issue, since concurrent thread may access inconsistent `TypeMap` while it is modified by a thread invoking `CreateMap`.

Comment: re CreateMap: isn't it only added to the list at the *end* of construction?

Comment: I think this question is totally valid. We cannot assume the library to be thread-safe because we haven't found evidence against it. It is the other way around: everything is unsafe until proven otherwise. I guess the author of this lib needs to step in.

Comment: To fully explain the case: I'm asking this because I'd like to configure automatter in-place, i.e. right before usage. I planned to configure it in non-concurrent context, i.e. ~ `lock (mapperConfigLock) { Mapper.CreateMap()....; }`, and I fear this is not enough now.

Comment: See e.g. this test code: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/CustomMapping.cs -  I can't imagine how `TypeMap` there can be added after `CreateMap` call. I suspect the entry is added right on this call, and modified by `ForMember`-like methods further.

Comment: Ok, an exact code from Automapper: `public void ConvertUsing(Type typeConverterType) { Type type = ...; this._typeMap.UseCustomMapper ...; }`

Comment: One more example: `private void ForDestinationMember(...) {
 this._propertyMap = this._typeMap.FindOrCreatePropertyMapFor(destinationProperty); ...`

Comment: Concerning thread safety of Automapper: IMO, the question is important. It's one of the most watched projects on C# on GitHub with all the consequences.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I'm looking at moving to clearly instantiated configuration - to make these kinds of things "obvious".

Comment: Will be fixed in 3.2.0 https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/473

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The linked [issue](http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/3197) more or less answers your questions:

> Mapper.CreateMap is not threadsafe, nor will it ever be. However,
>   Mapper.Map is thread-safe. The Mapper static class is just a thin
>   wrapper on top of the MappingEngine and Configuration objects.

So only use `Mapper.CreateMap` if you do your configuration in **one central place** in a threadsafe manner.

Your comment was:

> I'm asking this because I'd like to configure automatter in-place,
>   i.e. right before usage. I planned to configure it in non-concurrent
>   context, i.e. ~ lock (mapperConfigLock) { Mapper.CreateMap()....; },
>   and I fear this is not enough now.

If you are doing in-place configuration just don't use the static `Mapper` class. As the comment on the github issue suggest use the mapping engine directly:

```
var config = 
    new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers());
config.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
var engine = new MappingEngine(config);

var source = new Source();
var dest = engine.Map(source);
```

It's a little bit of more code but you can create your own helpers around it.
But everything is local in a given method so no shared state no need to worry about thread safety.

Comment: 'one central place in a threadsafe manner' - I think this anyway needs to be explained in the issue, since there is a plenty of room for possible mistakes.

Comment: Here is link to mentioned [github issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/514).

Answer (score 0):

This questions may be a little bit outdated, just want to record some of my findings after a little bit of investigation.

[Mapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/c968f34e58eed73e7cb40e8e52849408693eddb6/src/AutoMapper/Mapper.cs) is a wrapper class to wrap to create new configuration, and new instance of mapper inside static memory, so strictly speaking it is not thread-safe, but you can use it safe as long as you only initialize the configuration once.

[MapperConfiguration](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/c968f34e58eed73e7cb40e8e52849408693eddb6/src/AutoMapper/MapperConfiguration.cs) create new instance of mapper, and record the config inside its own instance memory space.

**TLDR;**

If you need to init the configuration ONCE only, choose the static API

If you need to init the configuration many times, and worry about the the thread safety, choose instance API