# Is Automapper Mapper.CreateMap thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, automapper

In our current project we are registering mappings in static constructors of classes which are called by multiple threads. Mappings in static constructors are relevant only for that classes. But still multiple calls of CreateMap can be run in same time. Moreover occasionally (mostly as copy/past issues) same mappings can be registered in static constructors of different classes.

I tried to google whether Mapper.CreateMap is thread safe or not. And I found only following:

In post [Is Mapper.Map in AutoMapper thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649250/is-mapper-map-in-automapper-thread-safe) from 2012 there is note in nemesv's answer that CreateMap is not thread safe and it will never be.

But I found an issue on GitHub [Static DynamicMap and CreateMap APIs should be thread-safe](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/473) from 2014 marked as closed in 3.2 release. Which suggests that CreateMap should be thread safe now.

Can you confirm that CreateMap is thread safe? I ran some tests and it looks like it should be but still if somebody with deeper knowledge could confirm this information it would be fine.

**EDIT**
After some additional testing it seems that CreateMap behavior is very interesting:

I used following code for testing

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var items = new List<EntityA>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new EntityA { FirstName = "A" + i });
        }

        ManualResetEvent stopChangingMappingFunction = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>
        {

            int i = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                if (stopChangingMappingFunction.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero))
                    return;

                var i1 = i++;
                Mapper.CreateMap<EntityA, EntityB>().ForMember(x => x.Age, y => y.ResolveUsing(new Func<EntityA, object>(a => i1)));
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            int i = -1;
            while (true)
            {
                if (stopChangingMappingFunction.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero))
                    return;

                var i1 = i--;
                Mapper.CreateMap<EntityA, EntityB>().ForMember(x => x.Age, y => y.ResolveUsing(new Func<EntityA, object>(a => i1)));
            }
        });

        List<int> distinctAges1 = null;
        List<int> distinctAges2 = null;

        Thread t3 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var res = Mapper.Map<IList<EntityA>, IList<EntityB>>(items);
            distinctAges1 = res.Select(x => x.Age).Distinct().ToList();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var res2 = Mapper.Map<IList<EntityA>, IList<EntityB>>(items);
            distinctAges2 = res.Select(x => x.Age).Distinct().ToList();

            stopChangingMappingFunction.Set();
        });

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t3.Start();

        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();
        t3.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("First Mapping: " + string.Join(", ", distinctAges1.ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine("Second Mapping: " + string.Join(", ", distinctAges2.ToArray()));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

public class EntityA
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

In all my tests when first Map method is called it means that CreateMap is frozen and no more changes to mapping function can be done (distinctAges1 was always one unique value and same value was in distinctAges2). Changing map function from two threads sometimes lead to increasing alternating values of Age from negative to positive numbers (tests ended with high value of distinct Age). But sometimes behavior was totally different and Age iteration stopped at value of 1 or -1. It seems there is some internal mechanism freezing changes to mapping function if this mapping function is changed from more threads. But this was not happening in 100% cases

Comment: @usr what makes you think it's not?

Comment: It was not thread safe at least until 3.2. Now it should be, but some "proof" eg. from documentation would be fine :-)

Comment: The question is clear, I wrote it to someones deleted comment :)

Comment: Please read here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649250/is-mapper-map-in-automapper-thread-safe

Comment: To Lior Dadon - Please read my question carefully. I am mentioning your link in my question plus I added another link which suggests that CreateMap should be thread safe from version 3.2

Comment: Well.... it's open source... you could just go ahead and see how it's implemented...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CreateMap is thread-safe. That doesn't mean your code calling CreateMap is. CreateMap should only be called once per AppDomain, the usual way is something like this: https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversity/blob/master/src/ContosoUniversity/Infrastructure/Mapping/AutoMapperBootstrapper.cs

Maps should not use any contextual data that's passed in via closures. The code you have above are bad maps to begin with, you should instead refactor them to use the built-in means for contextual data https://stackoverflow.com/a/31754133/58508

Comment: On that sample I tried to demonstrate changing mapping function. In real project this should not be not an issue.True is that we have CreateMap in multiple places (in static constructors of classes which needs mappings).The reason is better maintenance (having CrtMp close to place where that mapping fnct is used). Only issues with this approach can be in multi thread environment: One thread calls Map, another calls CreateMap. In very rare cases (ctrl+c, ctrl+v issue) CreateMap tries to register same mapping functions in more than one place. Thus I am interested in possible consequences.

Comment: The AutoMapperBootstrapper class linked to by @Jimmy has been refactored. The commit that removed the class is [here](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversity/commit/72de8369591ea688597ffb5fe0a5e9811c170d92#diff-094d858ff90f8bce14faec1458d417bf):